# resolve a promise until flag is false

Tags: javascript, promise

I try to write a logic that promise is fulfilled while a flag becomes false. Here is my code

```
let flag = true;

setTimeout(() => (flag = false), 5000); //set flag to false after 5s

const checkFlagPromise = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    checkFlag(resolve);
  });
};

const checkFlag = (resolve) => {
  console.log("check flag");
  flag ? setTimeout(checkFlag, 500) : resolve("done");
};

checkFlagPromise().then((msg) => console.log(msg)).catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

However, I got this error

```
test.js:34
  flag ? setTimeout(checkFlag, 500) : resolve("done");
                                      ^
TypeError: resolve is not a function
```

Where is the problem in my case?

Comment: When setTimeout recursively calls checkFlag, it does so with no arguments.

Comment: You are right, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This concept of "polling" a flag is generally a flawed way to approach this.  Instead, you should hook into whatever it is that changes the flag and make your code **event driven**.  This will both be more responsive and more efficient.  You could create an `EventEmitter` that any code that changes the flag fires an event on and hook your promise into that by listening for an event where it can resolve itself.

In your specific code, the error is caused because when you call `checkFlag` from the `setTimeout()`, you don't pass any arguments to it.  So, when it's called again, the `resolve` argument will be `undefined`.  You could fix that by adding the `resolve` argument to your `setTimeout()` call like this:

```
const checkFlag = (resolve) => {
  console.log("check flag");
  flag ? setTimeout(checkFlag, 500, resolve) : resolve("done");
};
```

You can see the fix work here, though a better approach would be to hook into the real code that changes the flag and use events instead of polling:

```js
let flag = true;

setTimeout(() => (flag = false), 5000); //set flag to false after 5s

const checkFlagPromise = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    checkFlag(resolve);
  });
};

const checkFlag = (resolve) => {
  console.log("check flag");
  flag ? setTimeout(checkFlag, 500, resolve) : resolve("done");
};

checkFlagPromise().then((msg) => console.log(msg)).catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Comment: You are right, I forget to pass an argument. Though, I should use an event-driven method as you suggested. Big thanks to you!